# The idea of eigenvectors and a transforming matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm reading this tutorial on PCA: http://nyx-www.informatik.uni-bremen.de/664/1/smith_tr_02.pdf

I quote from it:

> It is the nature of the transformation that the eigenvectors arise from. Imagine a
>   transformation matrix that, when multiplied on the left, reﬂected vectors in the line
>   $y=x$. Then you can see that if there were a vector that lay on the line $y=x$, it’s
>   reﬂection it itself. This vector (and all multiples of it, because it wouldn’t matter how
>   long the vector was), would be an eigenvector of that transformation matrix.

Here is the example they give:

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 3\\ 
2 & 1
\end{array}\right)  \left(
\begin{array}{c}
3\\ 
2
\end{array}\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
12\\ 
8
\end{array}\right) = 4 * \left(
\begin{array}{c}
3\\ 
2
\end{array}\right)
$

I have plotted the vectors:

[image]

All I can understand is that the vector got stretched. I couldn't understand the idea of the transformation at all. Where is the transformation here?

My questions:

1- What does 'multiplied on the left' mean?

2- What does 'reflected vectors in the line $y=x$' mean?

Comment: The example with $(3,2)$ has nothing to do with the bit about reflection in the line $y=x$; they are two unrelated examples of transformations with eigenvectors. Multiplication by the matrix in the $(3,2)$ example does transform the plane, that is, it maps every vector in the plane to a vector in the plane, but it doesn't have a geometric formulation as simple as "do a reflection" or "do a rotation" or "do an expansion/contraction".

Answer (score 1):

Multiplied on the left simply means that you take a vector $v$ and multiply it with the matrix $A$ to get $Av$. From the left is unnecesary here, but is sometimes useful as it is also possible to mutiply a tramspose of a vector with the matrix from the right, yielding $v^TA$.

Reflecting vectors in the line $y=x$ means that you take any vector and reflect it along the line $x=y$. This creates a linear mapping of $\mathbb R^2$ into itself which can be represented by a matrix. For example, it maps $(0,1)$ into $(1,0)$, it maps $(1,2)$ into $(2,1)$ and so on. The point here is that this linear mapping has a vector, $(1,1)$ (and all its multiplies), which it maps onto itself.

Comment: I'm still not able to understand the idea of reflection. What does it mean to "reflect a vector a long the line"? what does a linear mapping of $R^2$ mean? I would be so thankful if you can please provide visual explanations for this idea.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics)